# SQL Server : allow 3 letters and 4 numbers in a varchar(7) column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a constraint for a SQL Server table in order to allow only 3 letters and 4 numbers on a single `varchar(7)` column.

Example: `ABC1234`

Can anyone help?

Comment: You can probably use a trigger or two.

Comment: @PradeepPati - you should use triggers *when they are necessary*. It seems that this could be dealt with by a check constraint. You should use *specific* types of constraints when those will fit the bill and only consider triggers if constraints won't work.

Comment: Are those 3 letters/4 numbers specifically in that order, or any combination so long as the entire text contains that combination of characters? I.e. is `1A2B3C4` valid?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes, it should follow the same pattern (3 letters and then 4 numbers)

Comment: I would suggest going with @lad2025's answer as a safety, but I would also have something in the business layer to give better feedback and catch the "error" earlier.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I agree, I wasn't aware that we can use LIKE in the constraint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use:

```
ALTER TABLE tab_name ADD CONSTRAINT
constraint_name CHECK (col LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]');
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/VBGNTA8939)**